# Can I use RIA services from WPF?

Tags: wpf, ria

Or do I need a Silverlight client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, RIA services can be used from WPF, or in fact any NET Framework client.  However many of the client-side controls typically used with RIA are Silverlight specific, so your mileage may vary.

Comment: Is every steps are same to implement RIA services in WPF as in Silverlight or Do I need to do something new for using it in a WPF?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at [WCF Data Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/bb931106.aspx) too.

I'm still learning the differences so not quite yet ready to compare the two.